# Spring: Simpler FormHttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring's RestTemplate to send/receive http requests. I'm using Spring HttpEntity to create the http request. I use HttpConverters to serialize application objects in http requests and vice-versa. According to [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-resttemplate), there are 4 default converters:

- ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter,
- StringHttpMessageConverter,
- FormHttpMessageConverter,
- SourceHttpMessageConverter.

I'm using `FormHttpMessageConverter` to serialize several attribute-value pairs in a string so it can be sent using `RestTemplate`. However, `FormHttpMessageConverter` requires that http request parameters value is a `MultiValueMap` and, because of this, I need to do this for each attribute-value pair:

```
final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
final MultiValueMap<String, String> postParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

String attrib1[] = new String[]{"value1"};
postParams.put("attrib1", Arrays.asList(attrib1));
```

I'd like to use a simpler `HttpMessageConverter` that would accept a simple map for each param. Something like:

```
final HashMap<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
postParams.put("exclusiveOnly", "value1");
```

I know the former form is more generic, but I assume the latter would be useful to a *lot* of applications, so I wonder why it's not a default `HttpConverter` in Spring. Anyway, could you give me hints or point links how to create a custom `HttpConverter` to achieve what I want?

Comment: Am I missing something or does the documentation in your link state that FormHttpConverter is **read from and written into a MultiValueMap<String, String>**?

Comment: That is almost right, http request data is read/written into a MultiValueMap<String,String> by FormHttpConverter. Now I want to write a custom HttpConverter that uses a simpler Map<String,String> to read/write http request data.